# Extract domain name only from url, getting rid of the path (Python)

Tags: python

I've been trying to extract the domain names from a list of urls, so that `http://supremecosts.com/contact-us/` would become `http://supremecosts.com`.  I'm trying to find a clean way of doing it that will be adaptable to various gtlds and cctlds.

Comment: https://pymotw.com/2/urlparse/

Comment: just a tip to keep in mind - if the urls coming from sources you have no control on, remember that "//supremecosts.com/contact-us/" is a valid url too. (eg without http/https)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it using regex like this:

```
import re

text = 'http://supremecosts.com/contact-us/'

m = re.search('(https?:\/\/[^:\/\n]+)', text)
if m:
    print(m.group(1))
```

Working [example](https://ideone.com/iE4ewE)

Comment: Really nice answer, cheers

Comment: But why a regex based solution if you have `urlparse` in the standard library?

Comment: `urlparse` can also be used but in that case you'll have to concat the `scheme` & `netloc` to get the desired result, like this : `urlObj.scheme + "://" + urlObj.netloc`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using `python3` and don't want to use `regex` for the job

```
>>> from urllib.parse import urlparse
>>> url = "http://supremecosts.com/contact-us/"
>>> obj = urlparse(url)
>>> obj
ParseResult(scheme='http', netloc='supremecosts.com', path='/contact-us/', params='', query='', fragment='')
>>> obj.geturl()
'http://supremecosts.com/contact-us/'
>>> obj.netloc
'supremecosts.com'
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use regex to extract domain and sub domain of a URL.

```
/^(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:[^@\/\n]+@)?(?:www\.)?([^:\/\n]+)/im
```

i use like this to extract the domain from URL.
check whether this will works for you.

A single regex to parse and breakup a full URL to domain name,protocol,query like the regex below.

```
^((http[s]?|ftp):\/)?\/?([^:\/\s]+)((\/\w+)*\/)([\w\-\.]+[^#?\s]+)(.*)?(#[\w\-]+)?$
```

where Regex position are like this

```
url: RegExp['$&'],
protocol you are using at RegExp.$2
domain name at RegExp.$3
path at RegExp.$4
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably a silly, yet valid way of doing this is:
Save the URL in a string and scan it from back to front. As soon as you come across a full stop, scrap everything from 3 spaces ahead. I believe urls do not have full stops after the domain names. Please correct me if I am wrong.